# Are Rubik's Cube fewest move type challenges allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

We have [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) which lets us have challenges involving things other than byte count. So I wonder if [Rubik's Cube fewest move challenge (FMC)](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/fmc-fewest-move-count-challenge-method-tips/) type challenges are allowed. I see no objections but maybe there is something that prevents these challenges from being appropriate for the site.

Comment: Is brute-forcing the shortest solution within reach for programs?

Comment: Just a fair warning: the answers to the questions "Is this allowed" and "Is this going to be a good idea" may be different.  You should definitely sandbox this sort of thing.

Comment: @xnor I don't think computers can do optimal full solves yet on 3x3. Definitely not for 4x4 and above.

Comment: @pppery I think that is a really broad post and to be honest I'm not sure what the post is even asking about. At least shortest witness should be distinguished from any witness.

Comment: I don't see any site reasons to object to this sort of think, and I'm intrigued by the idea. I think you might as well Sandbox a challenge and see how it goes. Though maybe don't spend too much time on small details on the first pass in case you wind up changing the concept or scrapping it.

Comment: As far as I know, there are exact solvers for Rubik's cubes.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate can they find optimal solutions? and the standard metrics (QTM, HTM) are not the only ones that can be used for scoring.